# How do I use FAQ module views with accordion effect?

Tags: 7

I want to use a setup similar to the hard-coded `faq-page`, having the questions grouped by category, but having the answers hide/show with the accordion effect. I would like to add a jump menu attachment at the top of the page, but this requires setting up anchor links in the original view. I have tried using the various Views displays provided by the module, but these don't have the accordion effect. Is there a magic combination that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the [FAQ](https://www.drupal.org/project/faq) module uses views to display the answers, then you can install the [Views Accordion](https://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module, which creates a new plugin in views to render each result.

**Views Accordion:**

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
>
> It will take the results and display them as a [JQuery accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)), using the first field as the header for the accordion rows.
>
> For Drupal 7 the module integrates the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) plugin as a views style plugin. You can configure the options provided by the jQuery UI plugin.
>
> For Drupal 6 the module used it's own jQuery code, so a different set of features is available for D6.

[image]